# Discordie Channel Switching

Tags: discord

So I have your average Discordie node.js code, but I have no idea how to make this send messages in other channels.

The idea is, when a user requests something, it will go into a channel called requests.

```
var Discordie = require("discordie");
var Events = Discordie.Events;

var client = new Discordie();

client.connect({ token: "" });

client.Dispatcher.on(Events.GATEWAY_READY, e => {
  console.log("Connected as: " + client.User.username);
});

client.Dispatcher.on(Events.MESSAGE_CREATE, e => {
  if (e.message.content == "request")
    //make this send in a request channel.
   e.message.channel.sendMessage("pong");
});
```

Comment: I know this question is a year old, but I'd recommend switching to discord.js if you haven't already because it is much more up to date with discord's new features (audit log for example)

Answer (score 0):

```
var Discordie = require("discordie");
var Events = Discordie.Events;

var client = new Discordie();

client.connect({ token: "" });

client.Dispatcher.on(Events.GATEWAY_READY, e => {
  console.log("Connected as: " + client.User.username);
});

client.Dispatcher.on(Events.MESSAGE_CREATE, e => {
  if (e.message.content == "request")
   var channels = e.message.channel.guild.textChannels;
   var channel = null;
   for(int i = 0; i < channels.length; i++) {
       channel = channels[i];
       if(channel.name == "YOUR CHANNEL NAME") 
          break;
   }
   channel.sendMessage("pong");
});
```